# andLinux + LAMPP better than XAMPP?

Tags: linux, joomla, xampp, lampp

What do you think, andLinux beta2 + LAMPP 1.7.4 are better than XAMPP 1.7.4??? (both under windows, obviously)

Because im currently using joomla 1.6 with andLinux beta2 + LAMPP 1.7.4 and i dont have the classic XAMPP problems when using joomla like:
"JD.. cannot create directory.."
"Cannot decompress file"...
No more permission problems like properties security tab in NTFS filesystems

Also i can now use chmod in my LAMPP localhost folders and the decompression of tar.gz files is super fast. (faster than decompressing on windows filesystem)

So what do you think?, im right or is just coincidence?

Answer (score 2):

You don't even have to install linux to your hard drive, you can run it from portable flash drive and use XAMPP for linux.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Xampp for windows or xampp for linux instead of running xampp for linux on windows using an emulator/virtaul machine(in your case andLinux)